# Do dreams repeat/continue? Or is it just a perception that a dream repeated?

Tags: memory, dreams

During lucid dreaming, we sometimes feel that it is a repetition of (or in someway related to) a previous dream, but when we wake up, we can't recollect the first instance of such a dream. Why is this so?

Comment: What type of psychological or neurological experiment would you expect to be able to answer this question?

Comment: @Seanny123 see Horikawa et al. in my answer.

Comment: @Izhaki that's an amazing answer!

Comment: FWIW I know the experience you're talking about. I have dreams that reference previous dreams, but it's only after waking that I realize that the _memory_ of the previous dream is a fabrication rather than an actual dream. In the dream it _felt_ like a memory. Or at least that is the strong perception. I guess it's possible that I really did have the dream but the long-term memory isn't available to me upon awakening.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer: My answer is about recurrent dreams. I don't have any immediate sources to consult on the continuation part (and there are less references to it in literature), but I'd be very surprised if it is any different.*

## Theories

Firstly, there are many of theories that support the notion of recurring dreams. I know not of a single one that (explicitly or even reasonably implicitly) rejects such thing.

## On cognitive perception

Secondly, you talk about *perception*, which in cognitive terms equates *conscious access* (rather than *sensing* in everyday language). So if you can (consciously) perceive it, it must be a genuine mental process that made it available (with the sole exception below).

## Subjective reports = objective measurements

Thirdly, recurring dreams have been reported and studied for decades (in your case I'd probably start with [1]). Most of dream science is natively based on subjective reports. But recently, scientists have shown that monitored **brain activity** is **in agreement** with, and can **even predict**, those subjective reports [2].

So we really have all reasons to believe that what we perceive as a dream is what we actually dream.

## Possible exception?

The one exception for this, and it is **my own informed suspicion**, is that we *may* still have a Déjà vu (déjâ rêvé, in the question context) while dreaming - so it may be a false sensation after all. It is **the same informed suspicion** that tells me that if this happens at all, it should be **extremely rare**.

## Sleep's low retention

As for the latter part of your question:

> we can't recollect the first instance of such a dream. Why is this so?

If one is to make **gross simplification**, during sleep:

- Your **long-term** memory is **'not available'** to remember stuff.
- Your **short-term** memory is even **more volatile** than it is while you're awake (there isn't central-executive process to exercise retention).

For the same reason, we often remember a dream just after waking up, but unless salient we fail to recall it shortly after.

---

[1] Zadra, Antonio, and D. C. Donderi. *Nightmares and bad dreams: their prevalence and relationship to well-being.* Journal of abnormal psychology 109.2 (2000): 273.

[2] Horikawa, Tomoyasu, et al. *Neural decoding of visual imagery during sleep.* Science 340.6132 (2013): 639-642.